# Consumir dados automaticamente

Tags: javascript, react-native, restful

Estou iniciando meus estudos em JS e React-Native.

Desenvolvi um app que consome dados de um servidor MySQL que tenho hospedado no UOLHost, através de um API REST que implantei como uma function do Firebase.

Basicamente é uma lista das vendas que foram realizadas no dia. A questão é que para atualizar os dados o usuário precisa arrastar para executar um Pull To Refresh, isso me fez pensar sobre a possibilidade de assim que o registro for gravado no banco o meu app detectar isso automaticamente e atualizar a lista.

Vejo isso em muitos apps, mas pra ser sincero não imagino qual tecnologia é usada para isso.

Uso API REST? Banco NoSQL? Como sincronizo os dados? Existe um nome específico para tal abordagem? Por onde devo iniciar meus estudos em relação a essa tecnologia?

Desde já agradeço a atenção de todos

Comment: Bom dia Socket.IO é uma biblioteca JavaScript para aplicativos em tempo real. https://socket.io/get-started/   da uma pesquisada... é bem simples de usar acho que pode atender sua demanda segue um exemplo de chat usando Socket IO https://socket.io/get-started/chat.